# Is there a way for me to simplify this subversion pre-commit hook?

Tags: svn, sh

Is there a way for me to simplify this pre-commit hook? It seems a bit much to me

```
#!/bin/sh
message=`$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"`

# Block any commits which don't reference a ticket
if echo $message | grep -q "re #"
then
    :
elif echo $message | grep -q "references #"
then
    :
elif echo $message | grep -q "refs #"
then
    :
elif echo $message | grep -q "see #"
then
    :
elif echo $message | grep -q "addresses #"
then
    :
else
    echo "Your commit must reference a ticket to be accepted. For example, re #1234"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you could use either gnur's variant or use a pattern file:

```
grep -q --file="matchpatterns.txt"
```

which would contain every pattern you want to accept:

```
refs #
addresses #
ticket #
bug #
...
```

I like this more because this kind of list tends to become long very quick, making the inline pattern difficult to manage.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest and easiest to maintain!

Answer (score 1):

`if echo $message | grep -q '\(re\|references\|refs\|see\|addresses\|\) #'`

Should do the trick.

Comment: very nice, I should have known that regex has OR syntax!